# Escaping square bracket ] in sscanf

Tags: c, parsing, escaping, scanf, format-specifiers

I want to scan lines like

```
"[25, 28] => 34"
```

I wrote a small program to test it out:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        char* line = "[25, 28] => 34";
        char a1[100],  a2[100];
        int i;
        sscanf(line, "[%[^,], %[^\]] => %i", a1, a2, &i);
        std::cout << "a1 = " << a1 <<"\na2 = " << a2 << "\ni = "<<i <<"\n";
        return 0;
}
```

compiling this gives

```
warning: unknown escape sequence '\]'
```

and the output

```
a1 = 25
a2 = 28
i = -1073746244
```

If I change it to

```
sscanf(line, "[%[^,], %[^]] => %i", a1, a2, &i);
```

I get no compiler complaints but still

```
a1 = 25
a2 = 28
i = -1073746244
```

I know the problem is in the second token because

```
sscanf(line, "[%[^,], %[0123456789]] => %i", a1, a2, &i);
```

gives

```
a1 = 25
a2 = 28
i = 34
```

But I want to use a terminating condition for the second token. How do I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want

```
sscanf(line, "[%[^,], %[^]]] => %i", a1, a2, &i);
```

Note the three consecutive `]` characters -- the first is the character you don't want to match in the `%[` set, the second ends the set starting with the `%[` and the third matches the `]` character in the input

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned... I'm not exactly sure what you want to do here...

Assuming that the things between the brackets are always integers, you could just do:

```
int a, b, c;
sscanf(line, "[%d, %d] => %d", &a,&b,&c);
```

If you're really insistent about using regex and wanting some generic stuff passed in between the brackets, what you're looking for is:

```
sscanf(line, "[%[^,], %[^]]] => %d", a1, a2, &i);
```

the second regex should be matching all characters except the `]` at the end. I believe that you were trying to escape the `]` before, but this isn't necessary and the compiler is throwing an error because it doesn't know how to handle that escape.

There are 3 `]` in the capture clause for `a2` because the first is saying, "don't include this character in the character match set," the second is closing off the character match set, and the third matches the `]` in the `[25, 28] => 34` input.

If I totally misunderstood your question, just clarify and I can revise.

Answer (score 3):

It look like your question basically boils down to "how to include the `]` character into a `scanf` scanset". It is possible and you don't need to escape it. Specifically for that purpose the language specification states that when the `]` character immediately follows the opening `[` character or immediately follows the opening `^` character, that `]` is considered to be a part of the scanset, not a closing bracket. So, in your case the format specifier is supposed to look as `"[%[^,], %[^]]] => %i"`. No `\` necessary.

I see that you almost got it right, except that you forgot the third `]` character after the second scanset.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a compiler (or, actually, library) bug (though you do need a third right-bracket, not just two). According to the standard (C99, §7.19.6.2):

> If the conversion specifier begins with [] or [^], the right bracket character is in the scanlist and the next following right bracket character is the matching right bracket that ends the specification;

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
sscanf(line, "[%s, %s] => %d", a1, a2, &i);
```

Comment: -1 won't work -- `%s` matches everything up to the next whitespace, so it will absorb the following punctuation character (`,` or `]`) and the subsequent match will fail.