# How to escape right bracket in sscanf?

Tags: c++

I get a string `[192:4545:454:e33]:8888`, which I want are `[192:4545:454:e33]` and `8888`, here are my codes:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    char ip[64] = { 0 };
    int port{ 0 };

    sscanf("[192:4545:454:e33]:8888", "%[^:]:%d", ip, &port);

    std::cout << "ip: " << ip << std::endl;
    std::cout << "port: " << port << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```sh
ip: [192:4545:454:e33
port: 0
```

Seems `sscanf` think the first `]` is the match of `[`, so how to escape it?

Comment: `sscanf("[172.30.59.98]:8888", "%[^:]:%d", ip, &port);`

Comment: `sscanf` does not support regular expressions.

Comment: @user3121023 works for IPv4, but I have IPv6 also, check the updated question, thanks

Comment: There are no Regexs shown in any of the `sscanf()` examples on this page. It does support character classes with negation.

Comment: Maybe this one helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/5750501/1741542

Comment: @OlafDietsche if I want `192:4545:454:e33` and `8888`, it works

Comment: For IPv4 & 6, you can do `sscanf("[192:4545:454:e33]:8888", "%[^]]]:%d", ip, &port);` and then `std::cout << "ip: " << ip + 1 << std::endl;` (both `'['` and `']'` are removed)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks, actually, I'd like to keep the brackets :-)

Comment: Then you can either append a new bracket to the end of `ip` with `strcat()` or use a more C++  approach, etc.. Re-adding that last decoration to the string is probably the simplest way to go.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, this is a solution

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but maybe the following is too simple?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string ip{ "[192:4545:454:e33]:8888" };

    size_t pos = ip.rfind(':');

    std::cout << "\nIP:   " << ip.substr(0, pos) << "\nPort: " << ip.substr(++pos) << '\n';

    return 0; 
}
```

If so, then I will delete the answer.

Comment: change `ip.substr(++pos)` to `ip.substr(pos+1)` to avoid a sequence point issue and the solution is fine.